# ValidationError at /opd/ ['“OPDCashSheet object (2)” value must be a decimal number.'] How can a model-object be a decimal number?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

models.py:

```
class Opd(models.Model):
    patient=models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=CASCADE)
    bill_number=models.IntegerField(default=None)
    date=models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    service_name=models.ForeignKey(ServiceName, on_delete=SET_NULL, null=True)
    mode=models.CharField(max_length=5, default=None)
    amount=models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    remarks=models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, default=None)
    opd_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_on=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.patient.name

class OPDParticulars(models.Model):
    opd_particulars=models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.opd_particulars

class OPDCashSheet(models.Model):
    date=models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    patient=models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    opd=models.ForeignKey(Opd, on_delete=SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    opd_particulars=models.ForeignKey(OPDParticulars, on_delete=SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    source=models.CharField(max_length=10, default='OPD', null=True, blank=True)
    case_number=models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    mode=models.CharField(max_length=5)
    cash_in=models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    cash_out=models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    balance=models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    bank_oopl=models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    remarks=models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    created_on=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_on=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class BankDeposits(models.Model):
    opdcashsheet=models.ForeignKey(OPDCashSheet, on_delete=SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    date=models.DateField(default=None)
    amount=models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, default=None)
    bank=models.CharField(max_length=70, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    mode=models.CharField(max_length=5, default=None)
    bank_ac=models.CharField(max_length=25, default='ABC Pvt. 123456789')
    branch=models.CharField(max_length=20, default='XYZ')
    remarks=models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    created_on=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_on=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

forms.py:

```
class UpdateOPDCashSheetForm(ModelForm):
    MODE_SELECT = (
        ('cash', 'Cash'),
        ('bank', 'Bank'),
    )
    mode=forms.CharField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(choices=MODE_SELECT, attrs={'class': 'form-check-inline'}))
    class Meta:
        model=OPDCashSheet
        labels={
            'cash_in':'Cash-in',
            'cash_out':'Cash-Out',
            'balance':'Cash Balance',
            'bank_oopl':'To Bank',
            'opd_particulars':'Description',
        }
        fields='__all__'
        widgets={
            'date': DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
        }

class BankDepositsForm(ModelForm):
    MODE_SELECT = (
        ('cash', 'Cash'),
        ('bank', 'Bank'),
    )
    mode=forms.CharField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(choices=MODE_SELECT, attrs={'class': 'form-check-inline'}))
    class Meta:
        model=BankDeposits
        labels={
            'bank_ac':'Bank A/c',
        }
        fields='__all__'
        widgets={
            'date': DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
        }

class OpdForm(ModelForm):
    MODE_SELECT = (
        ('cash', 'Cash'),
        ('bank', 'Bank'),
    )
    mode=forms.CharField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(choices=MODE_SELECT, attrs={'class': 'form-check-inline'}))
    class Meta:
        model=Opd
        fields='__all__'
        widgets={
            'date': DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
        }
```

views.py:

```
def opd_view(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        fm_opd=OpdForm(request.POST)
        if fm_opd.is_valid():
            opd=fm_opd.save()
            OpdReport.objects.create(patient=opd.patient, opd=opd)
            if opd.mode=='cash':
                OPDCashSheet.objects.create(date=opd.date, patient=opd.patient, opd=opd, case_number=opd.bill_number, mode=opd.mode, cash_in=opd.amount)
            elif opd.mode=='bank':
                opdcashsheet=OPDCashSheet.objects.create(date=opd.date, patient=opd.patient, opd=opd, case_number=opd.bill_number, mode=opd.mode, bank_oopl=opd.amount)
                BankDeposits.objects.create(opdcashsheet=opdcashsheet.id, date=opd.date, amount=opd.amount, mode=opd.mode, remarks=opd.remarks)
            fm_opd=OpdForm()
        return render(request, 'account/opd.html', {'form1':fm_opd})
    else:
        fm_opd=OpdForm()
        return render(request, 'account/opd.html', {'form1':fm_opd})
```

Coming to the `view`, it worked fine when the `mode` was `cash` and it created the object for `OPDCashSheet` but when the `mode` is `bank`, it can not create an object for the same model, stating a `ValidationError - ['“OPDCashSheet object (2)” value must be a decimal number.']`. Now if this object could be created, it would have been the `OPDCashSheet object (3)` as the second object is already saved in the database. So where am I going wrong here? How can a model object be a decimal field? Please help.

**EDIT:**
Error Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/opd/

Django Version: 4.0
Python Version: 3.10.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'account',
 'mathfilters',
 'django_filters']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1551, in to_python
    return decimal.Decimal(value)

During handling of the above exception (conversion from OPDCashSheet to Decimal is not supported), another exception occurred:
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "H:\Sonu\Projects\Practice\Project versions\Roughs\slr\2. wrkg\rough1\account\views.py", line 15422, in opd_view
    opdcashsheet=OPDCashSheet.objects.create(date=opd.date, patient=opd.patient, opd=opd, case_number=opd.bill_number, mode=opd.mode, bank_oopl=opd.amount)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 457, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "H:\Sonu\Projects\Practice\Project versions\Roughs\slr\2. wrkg\rough1\account\models.py", line 139, in save
    super(OPDCashSheet, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 743, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 780, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 885, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 923, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1301, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1440, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1382, in as_sql
    value_rows = [
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1383, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1383, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1324, in prepare_value
    value = field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1560, in get_db_prep_save
    return connection.ops.adapt_decimalfield_value(self.to_python(value), self.max_digits, self.decimal_places)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1553, in to_python
    raise exceptions.ValidationError(

Exception Type: ValidationError at /opd/
Exception Value: ['“OPDCashSheet object (2)” value must be a decimal number.']
```

Comment: Please edit your question with the full stack trace for the error.

Comment: @solarissmoke I'm sorry for replying so late. I have added the traceback into my post, please have a look and let me know if you find something that might help me clear it out. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The stack trace shows that you have implemented a custom `save()` method on the `OPDCashSheet` model - it's likely that this is where the issue is coming from. Show us that method's code.

Comment: @solarissmoke Thank you so much for pointing that out buddy. Problem resolved. Thanks again. :)